# Why would wrapping a TSQL query in an if statement increase its runtime significantly?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, if-statement

I'm having odd performance difference when running the same query two different ways.  Literally, the only difference is whether its wrapped in an if statement.

This query is actually part of a larger one, but I've isolated it as the culprit.

Running the query by itself returns almost immediately (returns 0)

```
select COUNT(*) from Responses r where r.ResponseID not in (
    select ResponseID from data.GamingReport_Computerized
))
```

Ultimately, I want to avoid running complex calculations based on the result of that query, so I wrap it in an if statement like so, but it takes much longer to run (~10 seconds) and I can't figure out why:

```
if (0 = (select COUNT(*) from Responses r where r.ResponseID not in (
    select ResponseID from data.GamingReport_Computerized
)))
begin select 'update will be skipped to save time' end
else begin select 'missing rows will be inserted' end
```

The data set does not change so in both cases the result is zero / 'update will be skipped', and yet running these two versions of the same query always results in the first version completing quickly, and the second version taking about 10-12 seconds to complete.

Update: here is a screenshot of the query execution plans for comparison.  Why are they so different?  Its very unexpected to me.

[image: Query Execution Plans]
[image: Detailed Index Scan/Seek performance]

Update 2: In response to a suggestion in the comments, I wanted to mention that the following query performs identically to the second version above, with the same execution plan and no increase in performance (i.e. using 'exists' instead of comparing count(*) to zero makes no difference).

```
if exists(select 1 from Responses r where r.ResponseID not in (
    select ResponseID from data.GamingReport_Computerized
))
begin select 'missing rows will be inserted' end
else begin select 'update will be skipped to save time' end
```

Comment: I'm about to add an image of the execution plans for comparison.

Comment: Instead of using `IF 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...)` use `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM...)`. You will see big improvement

Comment: I tried that already, but saw the same results.

Comment: Could you show the structures of PK and IX on the table?

Comment: Yeah, the gaming table has a PK (clustered) on ResponseID.  The Responses table has a unique non-clustered index on ResponseID, but the primary key is composite on other fields. I just can't figure out why it's not using the unique indexes on ResponseID the same way in each query.  In the faster case it's using a merge join (what I would expect), but when wrapped in an if statement, it suddenly decides to use two nested loops and an index seek instead of two index scans.

Comment: I hate to say it, but it seems like using 'select' in an 'if' statement is a killer combo, and not in a good way.  If I declare a local variable and use select to assign to it first, and then use 'if' on the variable, it runs fine.  It's only when 'if' and 'select' are used in combination (in the same statement) that the query plan goes haywire.

Comment: I'd *tend* to avoid `if` altogether - move that logic up to the caller, or move into a join, where possible

Comment: The problem isn't *where* the logic is... its SQL Server choosing the wrong query plan.  It must find rows in the Responses table that haven't yet been added to the GamingReport table.  The code that originally exhibited the problem was a single 'insert into select from' statement.  I noticed that query took a long time even when there were no rows to insert, which didn't make sense because the join and count itself could complete immediately.

Comment: But when I tried to isolate the logic to skip the insert, I discovered that every single method of performing that test exhibits the problem.  Whether I use 'A left join B', 'B right join A', 'B not in A', 'exists B not in A', 'exists A left join B', '0 = count(*) A left join B', etc.... no matter what form of the query I use, it chooses an incorrect query plan ONLY when placed inside another statement such as 'if' statement OR 'insert'.

Comment: The only way around it so far is to select directly to a temporary local variable first like `select @c = count(*)`, then test that local variable with an if statement `if (@c = 0)`.  If you try to do that in a single statement `if (0 = (select count(*)))`, the query plan is completely different, wrong, and takes orders of magnitude longer to the point where it's no longer feasible to run the update before each report is selected.  To the user, it's the difference between a report appearing immediately when selected from a drop down, or having to wait 10 seconds after each selection.

Comment: Strange: the "faster" query is using a clustered index scan (every row in the table), and the slower query is using a clustered index seek (a few rows).

Either the clustered index seek is taking that much time, or there is something else that isn't accurately represented in the plan.

Can you post the actual costs of the different scans and seeks (hover with your mouse). Also, for fun, can you try this:

if exists
(
select 1 from Responses r
left join data.GamingReport_Computerized
ON r.ResponseID = GamingReport_Computerized.ResponseID
where GamingReport_Computerized.ResponseID IS NULL
)
...

Comment: I can replicate the `If (0=` wrapping issue with live data, where a `select count(*)` that takes 1.6 seconds alone takes 57 seconds wrapped and the same index seek versus index scan. Using LinqPad to try to replicate the issue with Linq (though I expected I couldn't simply get it to generate an `If` on the SQL side) it generates `select case when [value]=0 then 'skipped' else 'inserted' end from (select [value]=count(*)...` and that runs quickly using the same query plan as the non-if one. BTW @DavidGriffiths, for me your "for fun" suggestion uses the slow `If` plan and takes about as long.

Comment: Anyone interested, there is more discussion on this at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1551954-3077-2.aspx (registration required). Summary: the IF expects one result, so does an index seek, without the if it expects multiple results so does an index scan.

Comment: @Ruskin, thanks for that link - interesting reading. If you go to the first page, it's Triynko asking the same question in a different forum.

Comment: Yeah, I posted the question there as well and received a lot of interesting posts and confirmation of this unexpected behavior. @David, I updated the question to include the actual costs of the query plan's steps with significant costs (e.g. index scans/seeks and merge joins) via mousing over the query plan elements.

Comment: Does it behave the same if you convert the `if/else` to a case statement in the where clause of the main query?

Comment: The 'case' behaves the same as 'if' (e.g. `select case when 0 = (THE_QUERY_IN_QUESTION) then 0 else 1 end`.  The plan is the same; same performance issue.

Comment: What about running the `(THE_QUERY_IN_QUESTION)` first and storing its results in a variable, and then using this variable in the main query?

Comment: @Trinynko, so the "TOP 1 (1)" that was suggested at SSC? I also read that flipping the logic around and using a NOT EXISTS might help.

Comment: @Triynko I have not attempted to confirm the `select case when 0=(THE_QUERY)...` for my data, but note that again splitting the query evaluation off into a "variable" like I mentioned above (`select case when [value]=0 ... from (select [value]=REST OF QUERY...`) does use the non-if plan again.

Comment: Interesting discussion on SSC. Slightly off topic as it's not your direct question but wouldn't it be faster/simpler to do the `UPDATE` unconditionally and if `@@ROWCOUNT` returns 0 then do the `INSERT`? I tend to avoid branching as much as possible and simply put both statements in sequence with the `UPDATE` first and the `INSERT` having something like `AND @@rowcount = 0` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: INSERT INTO data.GamingReport_Computerized (ResponseID, ...)
 SELECT ResponseID, ...
 FROM Responses T1
  LEFT JOIN data.GamingReport_Computerized T2
   ON t1.ResponseID = t2.ResponseID
 WHERE t2.ResponseID IS NULL

Comment: Russell, that's exactly the query I used to begin with, which was taking much longer than expected, and which instigated me to investigate this problem in the first place, by isolating the part of the update that was selecting the new responses.

Comment: @deroby, no it wouldn't be faster to do the update. There are millions of rows and we only want to run complex logic checking for gaming (involves SQL-CLR calls) for NEW rows. As I mentioned, it was originally done as part of an "insert into/select from/where null" statement (as Russell just mentioned) to insert only rows that weren't already processed, but since it was taking a long time even when there weren't new rows to insert, I drilled down into the problem to discover that SQL server was forming a bad query plan even with a simple query when using a select statement inside an if clause.

Comment: @James: "What about running the (THE_QUERY_IN_QUESTION) first and storing its results in a variable."  I had already mentioned that in the 6th comment above: " If I declare a local variable and use select to assign to it first, and then use 'if' on the variable, it runs fine.  It's only when 'if' and 'select' are used in combination (in the same statement) that the query plan goes haywire."

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem before (quite a few times).
Can you check if you're indexes are fragmented (and defrag them if necessary) and statistics are up to date?
That could have quite an impact on performance and is quite possibly the issue (as the seek is taking longer than the scan).

Comment: I had already updated the statistics, the indexes were recreated, and the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put both queries through Database Tuning Advisor (and take the results with a pich of salt).
It may suggest another index to create that would speed things up.